# In my React component TextField, why is the value always staying the same even when I change it?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, state, textfield

I'm trying to design a form control (TextField) for my React form, using material-ui.  I want a TextField to represent a field of an object, "mission," passed in to my componet.  I have

```
const MissionEditView = ({ mission, toListView }) => {
  ...

  const { handleChange, values } = useForm(mission);
  const recipientDisplayName = _.get(mission, "recipientDisplayName");

  const props = { classes, mission };

  function changeFormValue(name, value) {
    handleChange({ target: { name, value } });
  }

  function handleChangeRecipientDisplayName(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("value:" + e.target.value);
    changeFormValue("recipientDisplayName", e.target.value);
  }
...
                    <Grid item>
                    <TextField
                      className={`${classes.rootInput} ${classes.input}`}
                      id="recipientDisplayName"
                      value={recipientDisplayName}
                      placeholder="Recipient"
                      variant="outlined"
                      disabled={false}
                      onChange={handleChangeRecipientDisplayName}
                      fullWidth
                    />
```

The problem is, whenever I try and edit the text field component, the update doesn't take.  I can see the correctly entered value in the console.log, but the TextField value remains what it was when the component loaded.  How do I adjust things so that my update is reflected in my TextField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are setting the `value` prop of the TextField to the initial value passed in through the `mission` object. so it'll always be set as the initial value.
you need to get the value from the destructured `values` object

`onChange={values.recipientDisplayName}`